# How to properly validate method in struts by extending Action support class?

Tags: java, validation, struts2

Here is my snippet of code,

```
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {
     private String userId;
 private String password;
     ...........

     public void validate() {
    if (getUserId().length() == 0) {
        addFieldError("userId",getText("userId.required"));
    } 
    else if (!getUserId().equals("va1525252")) {
        addFieldError("userId", "Invalid User");
    }
    if (getPassword().length() == 0) {
        addFieldError("password",getText("password.required"));
    }
}
```

when userId field is empty I get error saying **Login Name is required** I have never set such error message , so what is the problem here?

here is our LoginAction.properties file which is in the same package as LoginAction class

```
password.required = Password is required
userId.required = UserId is required
```

here is our screenshot of login page when clicked on submit with fields empty
[image: Login Page]

Comment: the validate method in the action in in addition to xml and annotations, and possibly custom interceptors.

Comment: @Quaternion no there is **no additional xml file**(like LoginACtion-Validation.xml), I intend to do validation in programmatic fashion by extending ActionSupport Class , I am not sure of default interceptors behaving this way, I don't have any other files supporting validation